Autofac 8.0 throws error on IIndex<dataprovider, func<IDbContext>>
Actual class and its registration shown in below block
Repository with passing param as IIndex
public CycleDetailsMaintenanceRepositoryProvider(IIndex<DataProvider, Func<IDbContext>> contextFactory,
            IIndex<Type, Func<IDbContext, IQueryableRepository>> repositoryFactory, IMapperCollection mapperCollection)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    _cycleDetailsEntityModelMapper = mapperCollection.GetMapper<CycleDetailsEntity, CycleDetailsModel>();
    _genericEntityModelMapper = mapperCollection.GetMapper<GenericEntity, GenericModel>();
    _cycleDetailFlagEntityModelMapper = mapperCollection.GetMapper<CycleDetailsOrderEntity, CycleDetailFlagModel>();
}

registration
builder.Register(c => new DCReplenMaintenanceRepositoryProvider(
    c.Resolve<IIndex<DataProvider, 
    Func<IDbContext>>>(),
    c.Resolve<IIndex<Type, Func<IDbContext, IQueryableRepository>>>()))
    .As<IDCReplenMaintenanceRepositoryProvider>);

In older autofac it is working fine.
